# Proc SQL add days to a date

Tags: sql, sas, proc

```
Proc Sql;
Create table dates As
Select 
a.custid,
a.Displayed_date As Start_Dt,
intnx('day',a.Displayed_date,28) As Max_dt
From inscope_records a;
Quit;
```

Just learning how to use SAS EG so have created a proc SQL to add 28 days to a date. It works but it is giving me it in number format ie the days since 01/01/1960 I think it is, how do I fix this? Start_DT is being displayed as01OCT2018 as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need use the `FORMAT=` option after the variable to tell SAS what format to use to display the values of your new variable.

```
create table dates as
  select 
    a.custid
  , a.Displayed_date as Start_Dt
  , intnx('day',a.Displayed_date,28) As Max_dt format=date9.
  from inscope_records a
;
```

Note that SAS stores days as the number of days since 01JAN1960 so you could just use addition to add 28 days.

```
Displayed_date + 28
```

If you are using normal SAS code then use the FORMAT statement to attach formats.

```
data dates;
  set inscope_records;
  Max_dt = displayed_date + 28;
  format Max_dt date9.;
  keep custid displayed_date Max_dt;
  rename displayed_date = Start_dt;
run;
```

Comment: Cheers Tom that works a treat, so close but yet so far. Funny i did try the format one but my attempt looked nothing like that

Answer (score 1):

You can use these standard SQL methods

```
Date + INTERVAL 28 DAY

DATEADD(DAY, 28, Date)
```

Comment: Tried that

Proc Sql;
Create table dates As
Select 
a.custid,
a.Displayed_date As Start_Dt,
DATEADD(day, 28, Displayed_date) As Max_dt
From inscope_records a;
Quit;

But it didnt work

Comment: That is strange. Judging by this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 it should work. You should provide the result/error it gives you.

Comment: Just said dateadd function doesnt exist. @Tom below has sorted it for me, thanks for your help kars.

Comment: @Kars Manuals for Microsoft's implementation of SQL will not be useful for someone using SAS's implementation.  PROC SQL supports the ANSI 1992 standard of SQL.